# c++ unresolved external symbol itksys-4.13.lib, SystemInformationImplementation

Tags: c++, unresolved-external, itk

I am trying to compile a code where I use a class defined in a static library .lib.
this class is using itk functions, the includes are in the .cpp.

I give to my code, the .lib and the .h of the project defining this class.

When I try to compile I get this error:
[image]

the lib itksys-4.13.lib is well passed to the compiler.
in visual studio if I look at:
Project->Properties->Linker->CommandLine I can see it.
(it is passed using qmake. in the .pri:

```
MyITK {
  CONFIG_FOUND += MyITK
  QMAKE_LIBDIR += $${PACKAGE_LIB}/MyITK
  win32:LIBS += ITKBiasCorrection-4.13.lib \
etc...)
```

and in the .pro:

```
CONFIG += MyITK
```

)

I don't get why I have this error if the lib is there.

Comment: Look at the bottom of the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683219(v=vs.85).aspx) for the library you have to link.

Comment: thanks, I added psapi.lib to the linker and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need [to use](https://itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Configuring_and_Building) CMake to configure your ITK-based project, not QMake.

If you really don't want to use CMake, or for some reason can't, you can create a version of your project which uses CMake and copy the libraries used and perhaps some defines from it. There are a lot libraries, and your manual specification obviously missed some of them.

Comment: I can't use cmake. the software on which I do the wrapping needs QMake, I would have prefer CMake but I don't have the choice.

Comment: CMake can be used for Qt projects.